# Why does ConsentForm.load cause android ANR sometimes?

Tags: android

I largely copied and pasted the code from [Google's official Consent SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent).

Though it works without any problem most of the time, it sometimes causes ANR. It is becoming a major ANR cause.  I assume ConsentForm.load has to be run on the UI thread.  Is there a remedy for this?

ANR:

> Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the
>   touched window has not finished processing certain input events that
>   were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago. Wait queue length: 2. Wait
>   queue head age: 6676.6ms.)

```
"main" tid=1 Native 
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x74f5ef98 self=0xb8114c60
  | sysTid=18557 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xb6f28b34
  | state=S schedstat=( 1288189187 190774336 1785 ) utm=89 stm=39 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0xbe594000-0xbe596000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  #00  pc 0000000000016a6c  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
  #01  pc 00000000000f60bb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17ConditionVariable4WaitEPNS_6ThreadE+82)
  #02  pc 00000000003e4a23  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL12GoToRunnableEPNS_6ThreadE+502)
  #03  pc 00000000000e56dd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art12JniMethodEndEjPNS_6ThreadE+8)
  #04  pc 0000000000183663  /data/app/com.google.android.webview-1/oat/arm/base.odex (Java_org_chromium_content_browser_framehost_NavigationControllerImpl_nativeLoadUrl__JLjava_lang_String_2IILjava_lang_String_2IILjava_lang_String_2Lorg_chromium_content_1public_common_ResourceRequestBody_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2ZZZ+342)
  at org.chromium.content.browser.framehost.NavigationControllerImpl.nativeLoadUrl (NavigationControllerImpl.java)
  at org.chromium.content.browser.framehost.NavigationControllerImpl.loadUrl (NavigationControllerImpl.java:67)
  at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.loadUrl (AwContents.java:496)
  at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.loadUrl (AwContents.java:375)
  at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.loadUrl (AwContents.java:380)
  at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.loadUrl (WebViewChromium.java:227)
  at android.webkit.WebView.loadUrl (WebView.java:894)
  at com.google.ads.consent.ConsentForm.load (ConsentForm.java:271)
```

Comment: Any findings on this?